# Check if a datatable is empty in primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable in primefaces with jsf and I need to check when the datatable is empty with jquery/js, but I have just found tags for "normal" datatables that don't work on PF.

Bean

```
private ArrayList<Curso> curs = null;
private ArrayList<Curso> listado_filtrado;
private DefaultStreamedContent informe_cursos;
```

Html

```html
<p:outputPanel id="opTabla" >
  <p:dataTable id="tabla_elements"   
                 value="#{Cursos.curs}"
                 var="element"
                 filteredValue="#{Cursos.listado_filtrado}"
                 emptyMessage="No se encontraron elementos"
               paginator="true" rows="20"   
      currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} a {endRecord} de {totalRecords}"
         paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
               paginatorPosition="bottom">
                 
                <p:ajax event="filter" update="exportar"/>
                <f:facet name="header">
                 <div class="header-field-col">
                <p:commandButton id="anadir_curso" value="Añadir curso nuevo" icon="ui-icon-plus" />
              </div>
              <div class="header-field-col"> 
                 
               <p:commandButton id="exportar" value="Exportar" ajax="false" disabled="#{empty Cursos.curs}"  
                   icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-s">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{Cursos.informeCursos}" />                
               </p:commandButton>
               
       </div>
                </f:facet>
```

Comment: If you want to merely display a message, whenever a datatable is empty - contains no records, then an attribute named `emptyMessage` can be used.

Comment: no, i need it to disable a export commandbutton when the table is empty

Comment: Then add a disabled attribute to the commandButton that takes the same 'list' as is used in the value of the dataTable but add an empty check there...

Comment: it didnt work either

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo and see if the 'header' facet is a namingcontainer, or something else...

Answer (score 1):

Your `p:dataTable` most likely references a list. Add an ajax event handler to it for e.g. the filter (all the ones that can make a page empty)

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.myList}"...>
    <p:ajax event="filter" update="exportButton" ... >
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

use a `p:commandButton` with a `disabled` attribute like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="exportButton" value="export" disabled="#{empty myBean.myList}" ... />
```

It disables the commandButton client **and** serverside if the list is empty. So users cannot hack it client-side either.

The 'update' element in the commandButton makes sure the button state is, well,...  updated on the relevant events. This is all rather basic ajax stuff, maybe read some tutorial on that

Comment: i have tried this but, the button is disabled just when i update the page manually not

Comment: Then you need ajax events in the datatable, mainly on the filter, where you 'update' the commandButton

Comment: i have tried with an ajax event listen but it does the same

Comment: Then you have a different problem... This works for me in all the case I use it

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo it might help

Comment: I have tried this 
<p:ajax event="filter" update=":#{component.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer.clientId}:tabla_elements:exportar"/>
and this
<p:ajax event="filter" update="tabla_elements:exportar"/>

and the button didnt disabled it, i have seen the name in html of the button is "tabla_elements:exportar"

Comment: We cannot see if that is good or not unless there is a [mcve] in the question. And you can use backticks to 'mark' code  in comments

Comment: is there any other way to avoid the export when the table is empty? if i will not be able to make this way works

Comment: Sure, tell the user to **not** press the button.

Comment: i mean can i trigger a warning when the table is empty and the button pressed

Comment: Why is this not sufficient? It is the safe solution. Works client AND server side. Any other possible solution either works just client-side (and might thus be 'unsafe/untrusted') or becomes rather complex (as would a client-side solution). Others think it isa good solution (see the upvotes)